# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError issue

Tags: java, c, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface

I am creating a Java program using JNI to gather data via a C program.  I have gone through this JNI tutorial (https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/_java_native_interface_jni.html), and everything compiles correctly.  However, when I try to run the Java program in Eclipse, I keep getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no TurtleTrackerImpl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at main.TurtleTracker.(TurtleTracker.java:28)
    at main.Driver.main(Driver.java:54)

I include the library using System.loadLibrary("TurtleTrackerImpl") in the Java class of the same name.

I have printed out the library path to make sure it is correct (C:\Users\duril_000\workspace\ArenaTracker\ArenaTracker\src), and I have checked for the existence of the libTurtleTrackerImpl.jnilib within that path (it exists and I can even print out its contents within Eclipse).

There are a lot of other similar issues online, but I have not been able to find any where the library path was correct and the issue persisted.  Please assist--I cannot think of what would be wrong?  Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this exception happens when the system could not load your lib, because of its path.

Possible Exceptions:

1. SecurityException -- if a security manager exists and its checkLink
   method doesn't allow loading of the specified dynamic library
2. UnsatisfiedLinkError -- if the library does not exist
3. NullPointerException -- if libname is null

So, it seems you need to pass the full path inside the method `loadLibrary`, here is an example:

```
 // load a library that is Windows/System32 folder
  System.out.println("Loading Library...");
  Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("C:/Windows/System32/crypt32.dll");
  System.out.println("Library Loaded.");
```

In your case, try something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("C:\\Users\\duril_000\\workspace\\ArenaTracker\\ArenaTracker\\src\\TurtleTrackerImpl.extension");
```

Don't forget changing the extension and the double bars "\\"